.bat file to read data from a fixed width file and rename the file
Hi hoping someone can assist.
I need to create a .bat file to read a value from a text file at a certain position and use it to rename the file.
The bat file needs to read the 5th line and the text from the 47th character for 18 characters.
It should then take those 18 characters and use it to rename the file removing any spaces.
I have had a few goes but not been able to get this working so would appreciate some assistance.
Thanks,
G
I have tried to write a bat file and i can read in a line but not able to get the specific location.

Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please read [ask] a good question. Always include a [mcve] of the code you are using.

How to read the nth line of a file has been asked and answered multiple times before, as has getting n characters of a string from the nth character. Use the search engine at the top of the page, locate those code examples, put them together into a batch file and make a genuine attempt at the task. It is not our remit to do any or all of that for you. Our task is to help you to fix a single reproducible programming issue with your submitted code.

Thanks for the quick responses. First time posting on stack overflow so this is new to me. I did spend a few hours today trying various bits of code from this website but could not quite get it to work. I have been able to read in line by line but not capture text for a specific line and position in that line. I think it needs to be something like this :
`echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('c:\test\test.txt') 
if LINE:=5
set "LINE=!LINE:~47,18!"
pause`


If you have code you'd like us to assist you with, please use the [Edit] facility and submit it properly formatted. Please also include with it exactly what happens, or doesn't, as expected, along with your output/debugging.

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\Q78349565.txt"
SET "newname="
FOR /f "usebackqskip=4delims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO IF NOT DEFINED newname SET "newname=%%e"
SET "newname=%newname:~47,18%"
SET "newname=%newname: =%"
ECHO REN "%filename1%" "%newname%"

GOTO :EOF

The required REN commands are merely ECHOed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change ECHO REN to REN to actually perform the rename.
I used a file named Q78349565.txt containing some dummy data for my testing.
The usebackq option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source filename.
It would, of course, be possible to set filename1 from parameter(s) supplied to the batch, but you provide no clue about how the filename is provided.
The setlocal is SOP - it ensures that changes made to the environment are discarded when the batch ends.
You cannot substring a metavariable (like %%e), so it must be assigned to a normal variable for use.
You have not said whether the extension is constant, to be maintained, or to be replaced with the 18-character string.
the for/f reads each line from the file, skipping the first 4 lines. The variable newname is first set to nothing (to ensure it is not defined) and then is assigned the value of the entire 5th line. Thereafter, since it contains a value, it's defined, so the remaining lines do not override that value.
Then extract the required portion of the line, and then replace each space with nothing
And perform the rename using the resultant value.

Thanks very much @Magoo - this works perfectly. Really appreciate your help. Thanks also to other people that commented assisting me in the correct way to post. Next time I post here again I will make sure incorporate all your feedback.
